# Use of Block-quotes in Formatting Q & A's

Tags: discussion, formatting

When to use block-quotes, and when to not use block-quotes. Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of our formatting is simply *de facto* convention, reflecting the preferences of longstanding members who edit and post frequently. While there was some early attention to formatting standards, e.g.

- [Path for adopting EL&U formatting standards](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1210/path-for-adopting-elu-formatting-standards)
- [Style guide for questions, answers, and comments](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/525/style-guide-for-questions-answers-and-comments)

nothing like a formal style guide has come to fruition. Some individual questions of formatting have been covered in

- [What emphasis to use when referring to words?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363/what-emphasis-to-use-when-referring-to-words/444)
- [Formatting poetry](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/formatting-poetry)
- [Formatting a Quote](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4128)

Also related is

- [How would we like to format our keywords?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3091)

---

Based on my couple of years of participation here, I would say that **blockquote formatting is liberally employed on EL&U**. In particular, because this stack uses text examples rather than code, and because virtually every question and every answer entails drawing a use-mention distinction, authors and editors are very liberal with italics, boldface, block quotations, lists, and headings, and the case has been presented to [add smallcaps](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2433) as a further option.

The main exception is the [widely and much-despised preformatted code](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/529) format, against which tchrist has [made a comprehensive case](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4722/16052). They are tolerated in the rare cases where preformatted text is truly desired, as to [simulate tables](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/12998/16052).

Because blockquotes are the most distinctive way to set off certain text from other, they are applied wherever a strong distinction is desired:

**“Always”** when the situation would call for the traditional use of a blockquote in written communication, for example

1. [quoting passages of prose](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/56874/16052), including [other SE posts](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/33131/16052). It is not necessary to wrap images in blockquotes, [even when they are images of quoted text](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/215404/16052), though [some have](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/200677/16052) out of an abundance of caution.
2. [quoting more than one line of poems or lyrics](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/126760/16052), though it wouldn't be necessary if somehow the poem constituted an [entire answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/106592/16052).
3. [quoting dictionary definitions](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/189842/16052) or [excerpts](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2628/16052) from other references.

**“Often”** when

4. [providing example text](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24750) longer than four or five words.
5. [providing multiple examples](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1073) in succession, though this is not strictly necessary for readability when used in a [bulleted list](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2126/16052) or similarly distinctive formatting.

**Occasionally** you will see it used to set aside the main question from its background information, or where [headings would be more semantically appropriate](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/112/16052) but

> the author just wants the text to stand out.

I don't myself endorse the latter uses, though I don't consider them so egregious as to edit them out. I do edit to insert them for readability in the first five cases; if you look at older posts from 2010 or 2011 before the conventions were widespread, you'll find many more solid blocks of text that are much harder to skim.

Comment: Thank you for what is a thoughtful and seemingly comprehensive answer. What prompts my request for clarification is that sometime during my first month or two as a user I was informed that block-quotes were reserved for direct quotations, which then required attribution ... and, lately, I have been requesting the same of various users when I notice their answers departing from that convention. Also, the reason I've been encouraging the adoption of that convention is that I find it really helpful in quickly distinguishing a direct quotation from an authority, from personal opinion.

Comment: I see the point about distinguishing true quotations from examples, and perhaps we could indicate one or the other with a symbol. On the other hand, we don't have a consensus on how to mark accepted/not accepted uses, which would seem to be something pretty essential (not to mention standardized in linguistics)— some use asterisks, others exclamation marks, others characters like Ø.